# How can I drag images onto the canvas?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, bitmap, android-canvas

I am working on an app that loads an image and paints it in a camvas to edit it, but I want to add a section where I show a list of images and the user can drag and drop the image on the canvas, but I am locked in the latter function someone have an example or a way to perform this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this Android Developers tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) covers just what you need - a drag and drop process of an image. If you want an even more detailed tutorial, [this Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop) explains it well.

In short, you have to use the `onTouchEvent` method inherited from the `View` class in order to detect and apply the Drag and Drop process.